# how to add arraylist contents to menu in jsf 2

Tags: jsf-2

I want to add the contents of an arraylist  has meu in a jsf page but playing me anything can you help me !!!! thnks

this is the method where i fill my arraylist from database in bean

```
public List<String> profession_pere_list;
public String profession_pere;
//....setters & getters
public  List<String> getSelectProfessions() throws SQLException, NamingException{

    profession_pere_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    initctx = (Context) new InitialContext();
    Context envContext = (Context) initctx.lookup("java:comp/env");
    ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/reinscription");
    cnx = ds.getConnection();
    state = cnx.createStatement();

    rst = state.executeQuery("select profession from professions");

    while(rst.next())
    {
        etu = new etudiants();
        prof =rst.getString(1);
        etu.setProfession_pere(prof);
        //profession_pere=prof;
        //etu.setProfession_pere(rst.getString(1).toString());

        profession_pere_list.add(prof);

    }

    return profession_pere_list;}
```

**and my jsf page:**

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{etudiants.profession_pere}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{etudiants.profession_pere_list}"/>
```

**so i have this error unknown source !!!**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)


 cause mère 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator$GenericObjectSelectItemIterator$GenericObjectSelectItem.updateItem(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator$GenericObjectSelectItemIterator$GenericObjectSelectItem.access$600(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator$GenericObjectSelectItemIterator.getSelectItemFor(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator$IterableItemIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator$IterableItemIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderOptions(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the rason was a List modified concurently by different HTTP threads in ViewScoped bean:

```
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {
    private List<Object> list;

    public List<Object> getList() {
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
        // code which modifies list
        return this.list;
    }
}
```

Solution - synchronize access to list:

```
    public synchronized List<Object> getList() {
```

In my case I had sometimes your exception and sometimes ConcurrentModificationException.

I have also found another explanation:

http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/jsf_nullpointerexception_in_selectitemsiterator_java

When SelectItem label is null - you can also get your exception.